# How to fix LibreOffice 3.5 to start from launcher icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, libreoffice

Recently I installed LibreOffice 3.5 from debs (including the ones for desktop integration. Since then it behaves in a weird manner. Basically it won't launch from launcher shortcuts. Example:

- dash > libreoffice launched (launcher shows with 2 seconds delay) > 'keep in launcher'
- LO closed
- the LO icon on the launcher clicked > pulsating for 5 seconds, then stops > LO didn't launch
- I didn't look for open processes or anything and...
- dash > libreoffice launched immediately without problems

It also didn't remember recently opened items, but now it got fixed somehow.

Other symptoms:
- icon on the launcher and all menu categories appear with a delay of few seconds
- two writer icons appear on the launcher

What I did:

- used 3.4.5, uninstalled, installed 3.5 RC3, problems started to occur
- uninstalled RC3 'clean' per http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Installing_LibreOffice_on_Linux#Debian_.2F_Ubuntu_3
- installed 3.5 stable which is identical to RC3
- still same issues

I don't know if it is related but I use Unity test PPA:vanvugt/unity which I needed to solve the stuttering windows bug.

Any ideas?

Comment: Libreoffice PPA doesn't have 3.5 it's at release 3.4.5

Comment: Did you use the sudo apt-get to install as well? Also you are always better off downgrading an application when it's not working correctly than you are upgrading. Downgrading to better know and more stable versions are the smarter choice. I will edit my response if you respond.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: The problem still exists, even on my clean install of Ubuntu 11.10 and LO 3.5.* from ppa:libreoffice/ppa. The official repository is still stuck with 3.4.*

Comment: The problem seems to be gone as I see it now in 12.04 as of September 2012 and I didn't care to try the solutions proposed here, sorry. Do any of the answers above contain a definite answer? I'd like to mark the question as answered if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Open Ubuntu Software Center. Search For LibreOffice Writer. Click on "Info" then See the bottom of Software Center. There is a Add to launch bar option. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed from .deb files, libreoffice filename will be libreoffice3.5-writer. So you need to edit the file `~/.local/share /applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop` and change the executable filename to libreoffice3.5 -writer .
Find and change **Exec=**

```
[Writer Shortcut Group]
Name=Writer
Exec=libreoffice3.5 -writer %U
OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

Comment: The question is specifically about launcher shortcut and you seem to pint to a desktop shortcut which I, for example, don't plan to create. Could you provide the solution in 'launcher variant', please? :)

Comment: @Bucic: Launcher icons are essentially files with extension ".desktop" . : ). Please try my solution and let me know. Also to be doubly sure of the filename,open synaptic and search for libreoffice. It will show up the installed files with file names.

Comment: Sorry, but the location specified by you does not contain any *libre* files on my system. Only some *wine* files. /  The only hint I've managed to dig out from terminal was "** WARNING **: Couldn't call /com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar.UnregisterWindow" after running "sudo libreoffice --writer" and closing it.

Comment: Firstly, you do not need a sudo for running libreoffice.  Easyway to find libreoffice writer file from the terminal is to type libreoffice in the terminal and press the "Tab" key. It will give you the available options for libreoffice. If you do not have a desktop file, create one for libreoffice. I will give you one.

Comment: type the following command in the terminal `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop`  and paste the following code in the file. http://pastebin.com/VwiRPZeH.  Then save it. Make sure to change the `Exec ` section to corresponding file name.

Comment: Did it. My exec line is now: "Exec=libreoffice3.5-writer %U". Now I can't run writer directly because it does not show up in the Dash when I enter "writer" there.

Comment: Also you didn't explain what should be the exact effect of these actions? Should new shortcut pop up on the launcher? Please don't expect me to guess it or assume I don't need step-by-step instructions just because I am the author of the question.

Comment: @Bucic: Could you try putting `libreoffice3.5 --writer` in the Exec =  section? Make sure to give a space before the `--writer` option. It works on my system. Also, if you run the same command from a terminal you will see Libreoffice writer popping up.

Comment: Done. 1. Writer still not showing up in the Dash.  2. issuing libreoffice3.5 --writer in the terminal returns command not found. 3. issuing libreoffice --writer launches the writer normally. Pinning it to the launcher brings me back to the starting point (see the description in the question).

Comment: i think you still have some libreoffice 3.4 builds left over, or you have added a ppa for libreoffice 3.5. If you have, remove the debs. The reason i am saying this is because, if its a build from Ubuntu repos or PPAs, then the filename is libreoffice. If its from the debs available at libreoffice.org then the launching filename will be libreoffice3.5

Comment: Yes, I did have LO PPA enabled. It's now disabled. At this point we can't go any further without a better clean uninstall procedure than the one linked in the original question here (wiki link). After using the procedure I still had tens of libreoffice leftovers in /etc/... , /opt/... , /usr/lib/... , /usr/share/... etc.